# vlc media player how do I get the menubar back?

Tags: vlc-media-player

How do I get the menubar back in vlc media player? its gone and I cannot find the setting  [image]

[image]

[image]

Here is what happens on rightclick
[image]

Comment: Right click>view>advanced controls

Comment: @Moab right click does nothing

Comment: What OS are you using? Works in Windows.

Comment: windows 10 using open-shell  @Moab

Comment: Did you right click in the vlc window? I assume you did.

Comment: @Moab  added what shows up when I right-click when playing video if I don't play a video then right click does nothing